# HuiFei Android HeadUp Unit not shutting down completely, ACC and CONST wires mixed up?

Tags: vw, wiring, audio

I Bought No brand Android head up unit from ebay (Hong Kong) here is a link to the unit [Generic android 4.4.4 car stereo](http://www.ebay.com/itm/201368248559)
My car is Volkswagen Golf VI 2010

The problem is that when I turn the car off the power remains in the stereo and it will not shutdown completely. I know this because the cooler still spins, even 8hr from the shutdown and the stereo wakes up immediately when I push the stereos power button, it resumes from only sleep mode. I'm afraid that this will drain my battery if i won't do something to this. This behavior is not normal. I have put the setting correct, so that when ACC is of the unit shut power down 30s later but this doesn't hapen. So I think the ACC and CONST wires are mixed up.

Can someone help me? Could this be the case, or is it something else?

and

Could someone explain me how to change the CONST and ACC wires crossed, and is there a potentially some danger by doing so?

Comment: Do you need help finding he CONST and ACC wires in the harness of the vehicle?  There shouldn't be any danger swapping them.  They are both +12v lines - one is on all the time and the other comes on with the key.  However, if they were mixed up, the unit would power off immediately when the key is removed (and doors are opened) since the CONST wire wouldn't be providing power to the right pin.

Comment: From your description the wires are then ok and this is just how the stereo behaves. So there might be a problem in the software.

Comment: If anything, you could disconnect the CONST wire and connect them both to ACC. That would "fix" the problem, but you might have to deal with long start-up times, incorrect clock, etc so it might not be an option.

Comment: also system looses radio favorites so might not be a good option for me, Ill just have to see what happens if I continue to use it this way. I might change the Operating system of the stereo, if that brings help to this matter.

Comment: Is there a way to measure somehow how much energy the stereo is using?

Answer (score 2):

There was one wire that could be connected or disconnected from the device, and it had been left connected as default and this caused the not shutting down problem and the device was constantly on. When I disconnected that cable, the problem disappeared, problem solved.